# issues with form validation in spring mvc

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc

I have an Entity as

```
@Entity
public class Foo {   

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @Size(min = 5,max = 50, message = "Valid title is 5-50 chars")
    private String title;

    @Lob
    @Column(length=1000000)
    private String description;
    @NotNull(message = "Location must be specified")
    private String location;
// getters & setters go here
}
```

and I have a method to save Foo as

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addDetail(@ModelAttribute("foo") Foo foo) {               
            fooService.persistFoo(foo); 
            return "redirect:/";            
    }
```

at this point if I submit form with invalid data I get exception as

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [com.rhcloud.pro.entity.Foo] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
```

Now I want to implement form validation as

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addDetail(@ModelAttribute("foo") @Valid Foo foo, BindingResult bindingResult) {

        if (!bindingResult.hasErrors()) {               
            fooService.persistFoo(foo);
            return "redirect:/";
        }else{              
            return "add";                           
        }           
    }
```

and add.jsp is

```
<form:errors path="foo"/>                           
<form:form commandName="foo" class="form" id="add">                         
    <div class="form-group form-group-label">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10 col-md-push-1">
                <label class="floating-label" for="login-username">Title</label>
                <form:input name="title" path="title" cssClass="form-control" />
                <span class="form-help form-help-msg text-red"><i class="form-help-icon icon icon-error"></i></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="form-group form-group-label">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10 col-md-push-1">
                <label class="floating-label" for="login-username">Location</label>
                <form:input name="location" path="location" cssClass="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-group-label">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10 col-md-push-1">
                <label class="floating-label" for="login-username">Description</label>
                <form:textarea name="description" path="description" cssClass="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10 col-md-push-1">
                <button
                    class="btn btn-block btn-blue waves-button waves-effect waves-light">Add</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form:form>
```

now if I submit form with invalid data I don't get exception and I redirect to  my add page but I don't see any error messages, but If I give correct data to form then the form is redirected to add page, I can not figure out how to get form validation done correctly.

Comment: Have you debugged the method to see more details?

Comment: How could I debug Please?

Comment: Try setting a break point on the `if` check in the controller, run it in debug mode, and view the `foo` and `bindingResult` in the debug window. Also, all your labels have the same `for` but they don't match the input.

Comment: OK after debugging I get `org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 3 errors` and their description, but how can I show those on my web page?